# Splitting a html page based on <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML PAGE:

```
<div id="d"
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <img class="select image" scr="something>
    <p>SPLIT HERE<p>
    <p>end</p>
</div>
```

Pseudo CODE:

```
var element = $("#d");
  elemnet.split("img").such that =
split_one = <p>one</p><p>two</p>
split_two = <p>split here<p><p>end</p>
split_three = Name of img class i.e = select image
```

HTML PAGE may containg one or more image class inside a div?

Comment: Not sure what's the actual question..? You can have N elements with given class name.

Comment: yes image class having  same class name

Comment: cool. so what's your question? :-)

Comment: How to split them ? I have mentioned it in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `split()`

```
html = '<div id="d"<p>one</p><p>two</p><img class="select image" scr="something><p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>end</p></div>';
html.split(/<img class="(.*)"\sscr=[^<]+/);
```

Output:

```
["<div id="d"<p>one</p><p>two</p>", "select image", "<p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>end</p></div>"]
```

You may use `exec()` as well

```
matches = /(.*)<img class="(.*)"\sscr=[^<]+(.*)/g.exec(html);
```

Output:

```
matches[1] // <- "<div id="d"<p>one</p><p>two</p>"
matches[2] // <- "select image"
matches[3] // <- "<p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>end</p></div>"
```

Using `replace()`; if you want the order mentioned above, the expression below would reorder the capturing groups

```
html.replace(/(.*)<img class="(.*)"\sscr=[^<]+(.*)/g, "$1|$3|$2").split("|");
```

Output:

```
["<div id="d"<p>one</p><p>two</p>", "<p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>end</p></div>", "select image"]
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/cunahote/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: I am little bit of confuse would you give me fiddle it would me helpful for me

Comment: @SomPathak Check the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/cunahote/1/edit?html,js,console) and follow comments. Feel free to ask if anything isn't clear enough :)

Comment: thanks man !!!! one more question if there are   more than one image class in a div and we want to split the html string on whenever a image class come i.e. text before image class and text after image class

Comment: @SomPathak Give me an example here please and I'll check it for you :)

Comment: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949516/splinting-html-before-every-image-tag)

Comment: @SomPathak Yes I saw the question but it is put on hold. Just edit it and say that this should be the output `<div id=\"d\"<p>one</p><p>two</p>
    select image
    <p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>More Split </p>
    select image 2
    select image 3
    <p>more split here<p></div>` and I'll add the answer. If they don't unlock the question I'll paste it here. No problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57977/discussion-between-som-pathak-and-hex494d49).

Answer (score 0):

use <kbd>[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)</kbd> and <kbd>[.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)</kbd>

```
$("img").prevAll(); // Returns all the elements befor the image
$("img").nextAll(); // Returns all the elements after the image
```

Comment: temp = $('#d')   $(temp.find('img')).each(function(){
                  
                   var sss = this.prevAll();
                    alert(sss)});

Comment: change `var sss = this.prevAll()` to `var sss = $(this).prevAll()`

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
var element = $("#d").html();
var split = elemnet.split("/<img(.*?)>/");
```