# Splitting HTML before every image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

```
<div id="d">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <img class="select image" src="something">
  <p>SPLIT HERE<p>
  <p>More Split</p>
  <img class="select image 2" src="something">
  <img class="select image 3" src="something">
  <p>more split here<p>
</div>

<script>
  // Pseudo Javascript:
  $('#d').find('img').each(function(){
    var split = split.images();
    alert(split);
  });
  alert(lastSplit);
</script>
```

After after image

```
split => <p>one</p><p>two</P>
```

After second image:

```
split => <p>SPLIT HERE<p>
         <p>More Split </p>
```

After third image

```
split => ""
```

If there is any text after last image it should store in last split

```
last split (if any) => <p>more split here<p>
```

I want to make it general, since I don't know how many image tags will be there in a HTML page. Anyone can give me a live demo?
Output div should be like this

```
<div id=\"d\"<p>one</p><p>two</p>     select image     <p>SPLIT HERE<p><p>More Split </p>     select image 2     select image 3     <p>more split here<p></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by split? what is the desired output format in the given case

Comment: Kindly provide us a graphical explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, [this should do what you're after](http://jsbin.com/fuwasemi/1/edit?html,js). The key is to walk through the sibling nodes and just split each time you find an img tag:

```
var splitAtImages = function($parent) {
    var splits = [];
    var currentSplit = [];

    $parent.children().each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is("img")) {
            splits.push(currentSplit);
            currentSplit = [];

        } else {
            // Use this to push the whole node
            // currentSplit.push($this);

            // Or, use this to push just the HTML of the node
            currentSplit.push($this[0].outerHTML);
        }
    })

    if (currentSplit.length)
        splits.push(currentSplit);

    return splits;
}
```

That may not be exactly what you need but it should get you started at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [],
    y = "",
    count = 0;


$("#d").children().each(function () {
    x.push($(this));
    if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
        count++;
        y += "Before Image " + count + ": ";

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y += " " + x[i].text().trim() + " ";
        }

        y += "\n";

        x = [];
    }
});

if (x.length > 0) {
    y += "Remaining text: ";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y += "\n - " + x[i].html();
    }

}
console.log(y);
```

[JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSxWT/18/)